# Creating a list of mutable items repeated N times

Tags: python, list-comprehension, multiplication, replicate

I have a list containing a set of `x` mutable items. I would like to create another list where the set of `x` mutable items is repeated `n` times. However, the items must be references to unique objects rather than simply references to the original objects.

For example, let `a = [[1],[2],[3]]`. Suppose I would like the numbers inside to be repeated `n=3` times, i.e. `[[0],[2],[3],[1],[2],[3],[1],[2],[3]]`.

I can do this easily by using `a * 3`. The problem is that if I change `a[0][0] = 0`, then I will get `a == [[0],[2],[3],[0],[2],[3],[0],[2],[3]]`, which is not desirable because I would like to change only the first element. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Just some pedantics: `1` is not mutable, though `[1]` is. What changes when you do `lst[idx] = val` is that the *binding* of `lst[idx]` is changed, the original value that the binding referred to remains untouched. Once you grok the underlying binding/immutability concepts, your Python skills reach a new level.

Comment: @paxdiablo. Ok I edited my question for future references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out I can do this through:

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
n = 3
b = [deepcopy(val) for _ in range(n) for val in a]
```

Now if I set `b[0][0] = 0`, I will get `b == [[0],[2],[3],[1],[2],[3],[1],[2],[3]]`.

Comment: It appears that `b[0] = 1` has set it to zero :-)

Comment: @Synthase: terms like "below" or "above" are a bad idea on a site where order can change.

Comment: @paxdiablo well must be too late for me ahaha

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` has a method for this called [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat). Just pair it with [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

a = [1,2,3]

b = list(chain(*repeat(a, 3)))
```

---

```
>>> b
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Comment: Doesn't that give `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
n = [sub_a.copy() for sub_a in a] * 3
```

You need `copy()` to avoid the problem.

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]

n = [sub_a.copy() for sub_a in a] * 3

a[0] = [-1]
a[2][0] = -1

print (n)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: This will just create three references to the same underlying copy, effectively changing nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `copy()` will create a shallow copy according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). Did you mean `deepcopy()`?

Comment: Well, I may be wrong on the exact terminology I edited. copy() is sufficient to do what you want tho, as deepcopy() should be too I think.

Comment: @Synthase Well, of course your code "works", because `a` is a list of integers. Integers are immutable. The OP was specifically asking about a collection of mutable objects. Try this with a list of lists.

Comment: @Paul, as far as I see, the OP took integers in the example. Sorry to use the OP's example.

Comment: @Synthase I agree, the OP didn't make it immediately obvious what they were after by using a list of integers as an example.

Comment: Changed my example into a list of lists. Sorry about the unclear example.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
a = a*3  
a[0] =0
print(a)
```

Comment: If you get the id of the first two `2`s (`id(a[1])` and `id(a[4])`), you'll see they're the *same* object.

Answer (score 0):

To get new instances of mutable objects, you can map the object type's copy() method to the multiplied list:

```
a  = [{1},{2},{3}]
b  = [*map(set.copy,a*3)]

a[0].add(7)
b[0].add(8)
b[3].add(9)
print(a) # [{1, 7}, {2}, {3}]
print(b) # [{8, 1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 9}, {2}, {3}, {1}, {2}, {3}]
```

If you don't know the type of the items, or if they have different types, you can do it in a list comprehension:

```
b = [ i.copy() for i in a*3 ]
```

If not all of the items are mutable, you can do it like this:

```
b = [type(i)(i) for i in a*3]
```

If some can be None ...

```
b = [i if i is None else type(i)(i) for i in a*3]
```

You can also use deepcopy which covers all these cases including objects that contain nested objects ...

```
from copy import deepcopy
b  = [*map(deepcopy,a*3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, you need to make copies of `a`, rather than repeating references to the original, mutable object.  If you need just one level of copy, you can do it like this, noting that it's a *shallow* copy (see second output).

```
a = [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3]]
b = a[:] * 3
b[0] = "change"
print(b)
b[2][1] = "deep"
print(b)
```

Output:

```
['change', [2], [3, 3, 3], [1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3], [1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3]]
['change', [2], [3, 'deep', 3], [1, 1], [2], [3, 'deep', 3], [1, 1], [2], [3, 'deep', 3]]
```

See how only the first level is given a new reference.  When you try to change a deeper element, you see that the nested lists are still the same object.  To fix *that* problem, use a deep copy for each element of `b`:

```
import copy

a = [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3]]
b = [copy.deepcopy(a) for _ in range(3)]
b[0] = "change"
print(b)
b[2][1] = "deep"
print(b)
```

Output:

```
['change', [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3]], [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3]]]
['change', [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3]], [[1, 1], 'deep', [3, 3, 3]]]
```